# adding @react-native-voice/voice to a react native project

Tags: react-native, react-native-voice

I am trying to add the @react-native-voice/voice library to my react native project:
Here is the picture of the package.json file:

[image]

the problem is that I get the file compilation error:

[image]

Is there any inconsistency between the @react-native-voice/voice package and the whole react native configuration?

Thaks in advance

Kobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different version of react-native-voice. I'm using this version and it's working fine.

react-native-voice: "https://github.com/hoangphan2202/voice.git"